# How do I use the diamond operator as a function call argument in scalar context?

Tags: perl, diamond-operator

How can I directly pass a value from the diamond operator to a function (sub)?

I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Math::Complex;

#quadraticEq - quadratic equation with parameters a ,b ,c
sub quadraticEq {
    print "\nx1= ", 
      ($_[1]*$_[1]-sqrt($_[1]*$_[1]-4*$_[0]*$_[2]))/(2*$_[0]),
      "\nx2= ",
      ($_[1]*$_[1]+sqrt($_[1]*$_[1]-4*$_[0]*$_[2]))/(2*$_[0]);
}

print 'Enter Numbers:';
quadraticEq(<>,<>,<>); #here
```

But I need to enter EOF when I enter numbers for each of the function arguments. It behaves as `@array=<>`. I want it to behave like `$var=<>`. So the input should look like this:

```
Enter Numbers: 5 4 3
```

Comment: For God's sake, shift out your subroutine arguments! Then you can use much clearer names like `$a`, `$b`, `$c` which are much more readable. (Make sure you lexicalize `$a` and `$b` at least, though)

Comment: Oh my god!  Kill it!  Kill it with fire!

Comment: But I did this on purpose.Don't bother with what function does.

Comment: Er, we know you did it on purpose.  It makes it infinitely harder to understand this way than if you assign the indexes to variables at the start of the subroutine. :)

Comment: @kr85: If you did this on purpose, know that it's "programmers" like you who give Perl such a bad name. Readability should be your first concern-- it is ALWAYS possible to write a correct program in Perl (assuming the problem is Turing-computable of course) without resorting to illegibility.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: That is tangential to the question, and also not really true. There are some limited situations where optimised code is preferable to readable code. Although I doubt this is one of them, we don't know what the OP's problem is. It *could be* such a situation. Without knowing anything about the problem, I find your comments a little patronising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to show you a couple of best practices while I help you with your question...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;     # strict/warnings helps detect lots of bugs and logic issues,
use warnings;   # so always use them

use Math::Complex; # WHITESPACE IS YOUR FRIEND

#quadraticEq - quadratic equation with parameters a ,b ,c

sub quadraticEq{
    # Shift out your subroutine variables one at a time, or assign them to a list.
    my ($a, $b, $c) = @_;

    print "\nx1= ", 
      ($b*$b-sqrt($b*$b-4*$a*$c))/(2*$a), # You're wrong on your formula btw
      "\nx2= ",
      ($b*$b+sqrt($b*$b-4*$a*$c))/(2*$a);
}

print 'Enter Numbers: ';

# Perl only supports reading in a line at a time, so... if you want all your
# inputs on one line, read one line.
# EDIT: That's not strictly true, since you can change the input record separator,
# but it's just simpler this way, trust me.

my $line = <>;

# Then you can split the line on whitespace using split.
my @coefficients = split /\s+/, $line;

# You should check that you have at least three coefficients and that they
# are all defined!

quadraticEq(@coefficients);
```

Comment: As I alluded to above, your quadratic formula is wrong too. You should start with `-$b` at the beginning of the formula, not `$b*$b`.

Comment: What's with this putting newlines at the beginning of the output.  Put them at the end.  The buffer is not flushed until a newline is encountered, so you should always put them at the end.

Comment: Good point. Should have mentioned that. You'll notice that it was in the original question though.

Comment: You could parse the input simpler with: `my @coefficients = split /\s+/, <>;`. Then you don't need the `my $line = <>;`.

Comment: +1 Another good practice would be to have `quadraticEq` simply return a string. Let the caller handle printing. Such an approach facilitates unit testing, re-use, etc.

Answer (score 5):

A naked `<>` operator inside a list of function arguments is always called in list context. But there are many ways to force the scalar context that you want:

```
quadraticEq(scalar <>, scalar <>, scalar <>);
quadraticEq("" . <>, "" . <>, "" . <>);
quadraticEq(0 + <>, 0 + <>, 0 + <>);  # if you want to evaluate as numbers anyway
```

Note that `<>` in scalar context will read from the input up to the next "record separator". which by default is your system's newline, so the default behavior of the code above is to read separate values from each line. If (as the original post suggests) the inputs are space separated and all on one line, then you will need to either:

1. Set the record separator to a space (`$/ = " "`) before calling `<>`, or
2. Use a different scheme, like `split` to parse a line of input into separate values

```
# read a line of input and extract 3 whitespace-separated values
quadraticEq( split /\s+/, <>, 3 );
```

For a problem like this, I would almost always go with #2, but There Is More Than One Way To Do It.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when passing values to subroutines, Perl uses list context, so what you're doing is using <> the same way as

```
my @args = (<>, <>, <>);
```

Which, obviously, isn't what you want!

You can force scalar context with the `scalar` keyword:

```
my @args = ( scalar <>, scalar <>, scalar <>); # read one
```

Or, read them all into variables, so that people know what you intend:

```
my $first = <>;
my $second = <>;
my $third = <>;
```

On an aside, you should really parse the arguments out of @_ before using them.  It'll make your function supremely more understandable.  An example:

```
sub quadratic2 {
    my ($a, $b, $c) = @_;
    ... # now use the actual symbols instead of array indexes
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
quadraticEq(map scalar <>, 1..3);
```

See also [perldoc -f readline](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html).